# Pressing the button and using the command, discord.py(python)

Tags: python, discord.py

Good afternoon, I would like to know how to make the participant press the button and say the /pause command, in advance here is the code of the button itself

```
    @discord.ui.button(emoji = "<:pause:1136251002215989248>", style = discord.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id = 'pauseplay')
    async def pauseplay_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        try: 
        except: await interaction.response.send_message('Ошибка', ephemeral = True)
```

What to put after try:?

I tried to use your text `await interaction.send('/pause')` , but it gives an error that I can't fix, thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the error message to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`tree.get_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=tree%20get_command#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.get_command) method to get your command, then use the [`.callback`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=tree%20get_command#discord.app_commands.Command.callback) attribute to get your callback object.

Remember however to pass *all* the necessary arguments that the pause command might need.

Here's a small example:

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(
        emoji="<:pause:1136251002215989248>", 
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary,
        custom_id='pauseplay'
    )
    async def pauseplay_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        command = interaction.client.tree.get_command(
            "pause", guild=interaction.guild
        )

        try:
            can_run = await command._check_can_run(interaction)
        except Exception as exc:
            return await interaction.response.send_message(f"An error occured while trying to invoke the /pause command:\n{exc.__class__.__name__}: {exc}")

        if can_run:
            await command.callback(interaction, OTHER, ARGUMENTS)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You cannot run this command.", ephemeral=True)
```